# Addressing Curve Misalignment in Matrix Minima Index Mapping

Tags: matlab, sorting

I'm currently working on a project where I'm tasked with identifying the minima in each row of a matrix `A`. For context, matrix `A` has dimensions 1951x450, and the minima are recorded in a separate matrix `B` sized 450x13. Matrix `B` indicates the indices of the minima locations in matrix `A`.

Each column of matrix `B` represents a "curve" in matrix `A`, essentially indicating where the minima occur. Picture matrix `A` as a function's values determined on a meshgrid.

The issue I'm encountering is that the distinct curves in `A` aren't accurately reflected in `B`. Sometimes, a row is "shifted," leading to inconsistencies in representing the curves. Visually, this can be observed as changes in color in the provided figure. My objective is to ensure that each curve is consistently represented by a single color, meaning they should all be in the same column of `B`.

[image: Figure for visualisation]

```
syms A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2 A3 B3 C3 D3 k x z omega t d1 d2 d3

syms ux1 uz1 stresszz1 stresszx1 stressxx1
syms cL1 cT1 rho1 
syms ux2 uz2 stresszz2 stresszx2 stressxx2
syms cL2 cT2 rho2 
syms ux3 uz3 stresszz3 stresszx3 stressxx3
syms cL3 cT3 rho3 

% 2D matrix
% stresszx at z=0
% stresszz at z=0
% stresszx at z=d1
% stresszz at z=d1
% ux at z=d1
% uz at z=d1

%%%%
% Pyrex glass from https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/sound-speed-solids-d_713.html
% Stainless steel from https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/sound-speed-solids-d_713.html
cT1 = 3280;
cT2 = 3100;
cL1 = 5640;
cL2 = 5790;
rho1 = 2230; % Should be for Pyrex glass
rho2 = 7500; % Can vary depending on the composition
d1 = 0.01;
%%%%


M11 =  @(omega,k)-cT1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).*rho1.*2i;
M12 =  @(omega,k)cT1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).*rho1.*2i;
M13 =  @(omega,k)-cT1.^2.*rho1.*(k.^2 + sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).^2);
M14 =  @(omega,k)-cT1.^2.*rho1.*(k.^2 + sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).^2);
M15 =  @(omega,k)0;
M16 =  @(omega,k)0;

M21 =  @(omega,k)-rho1.*(k.^2.*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2) - cL1.^2.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).^2);
M22 =  @(omega,k)-rho1.*(k.^2.*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2) - cL1.^2.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).^2);
M23 =  @(omega,k)rho1.*(k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2).*1i - cL1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*1i);
M24 =  @(omega,k)-rho1.*(k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2).*1i - cL1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*1i);
M25 =  @(omega,k)0;
M26 =  @(omega,k)0;

M31 =  @(omega,k)-cT1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).*rho1.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)).*2i;
M32 =  @(omega,k)cT1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).*rho1.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)).*2i;
M33 =  @(omega,k)-cT1.^2.*rho1.*(k.^2.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)) + sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).^2.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)));
M34 =  @(omega,k)-cT1.^2.*rho1.*(k.^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)) + sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)));
M35 =  @(omega,k)-cT2.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2).*rho2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2)).*2i;
M36 =  @(omega,k)cT2.^2.*rho2.*(k.^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT2).^2)) + sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT2).^2).^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT2).^2)));

M41 =  @(omega,k)-rho1.*(k.^2.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)).*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2) - cL1.^2.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).^2.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)));
M42 =  @(omega,k)-rho1.*(k.^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)).*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2) - cL1.^2.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)));
M43 =  @(omega,k)rho1.*(k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)).*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2).*1i - cL1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)).*1i);
M44 =  @(omega,k)-rho1.*(k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)).*(cL1.^2 - 2.*cT1.^2).*1i - cL1.^2.*k.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)).*1i);
M45 =  @(omega,k)rho2.*(k.^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2)).*(cL2.^2 - 2.*cT2.^2) - cL2.^2.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2).^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2)));
M46 =  @(omega,k)rho2.*(k.^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2)).*(cL2.^2 - 2.*cT2.^2) - cL2.^2.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2).^2.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2)));

M51 =  @(omega,k)k.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)).*1i;
M52 =  @(omega,k)k.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2)).*1i;
M53 =  @(omega,k)sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2));
M54 =  @(omega,k)-sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2).*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2));
M55 =  @(omega,k)-k.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2)).*1i;
M56 =  @(omega,k)sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT2).^2).*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT2).^2));

M61 =  @(omega,k) -sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2));
M62 =  @(omega,k)sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2).*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL1).^2));
M63 =  @(omega,k)k.*exp(-d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)).*1i;
M64 =  @(omega,k)k.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT1).^2)).*1i;
M65 =  @(omega,k)-sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2).*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cL2).^2));
M66 =  @(omega,k)-k.*exp(d1.*sqrt(k.^2-(omega/cT2).^2)).*1i;



%%%%
K = 50:1:2000;
OMEGA = 10^-6:0.2*10^5:9*10^6;
[OMEGAM,KM] = meshgrid(OMEGA,K);
%%%%



M_2D_matrix = {M11 M12 M13 M14 M15 M16
    M21 M22 M23 M24 M25 M26
    M31 M32 M33 M34 M35 M36
    M41 M42 M43 M44 M45 M46
    M51 M52 M53 M54 M55 M56
    M61 M62 M63 M64 M65 M66
    };

M_4D_array = zeros(6,6,length(K),length(OMEGA));
for i = 1:6
    for j = 1:6
        M_4D_array(i,j,:,:) = M_2D_matrix{i,j}(OMEGAM,KM);
    end
end

%%%% Chat GPT-code

% Example 4D array A with size [m, n, p, q]
[m, n, p, q] = size(M_4D_array);

% Reshape A to a 2D array where the first two dimensions are collapsed into one
A_reshaped = reshape(M_4D_array, m*n, []);

% Reshape the array so that each column corresponds to a 2D slice of the original data
A_reshaped = reshape(A_reshaped, m, n, []);

% Calculate the determinant along the first two dimensions for each slice
determinants = arrayfun(@(x) log(abs(det(A_reshaped(:, :, x)))), 1:size(A_reshaped, 3));

% Reshape the determinants array to match the original dimensions of the third and fourth dimensions
determinants = reshape(determinants, p, q);

%OMEGAM(:,1) = [];
%KM(:,1) = [];
%determinants(:,1) = [];
%disp(size(determinants))
%figure('name', '3D plot dispersiekrommen')
%surf(OMEGAM,KM, determinants,'EdgeColor','none')
%title('3D plot dispersiekrommen')
%xlabel('omega')
%ylabel('k')

%%%% ChatGPT code

% Loop over the indices of OMEGA
for i = 1:length(OMEGA)
    % Find the minimum value index using zoekmin
    min_index = zoekmin(determinants(:,i));
    
    % Get the corresponding values of K using the found minimum index
    Dummy = K(min_index);
    
    % Calculate Dispersion_matrix for this OMEGA index
    Dispersion_matrix(i, 1:numel(Dummy)) = OMEGA(i) ./ Dummy;
end
%%%%

%disp(Dispersion_matrix)
hold on
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,1),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,2),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,3),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,4),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,5),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,6),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,7),".")
scatter(OMEGA,Dispersion_matrix(:,8),".")
hold off
```

The following is the zoekmin function

```
function [I,J]=zoekmin(x);
%function [I,J]=zoekmin(x);
%last change 13-1-2003

y=(diff(x)./abs(diff(x))+1)/2;
[r,k]=size(x);
if ((r>1)&(k>1)),
 [I,J]=find(diff(y)>0);
 I=I+1;
 else,
 I=find(diff(y)>0)+1;
 J=[];
 end;
```

Comment: We'll need the definition of both `zoekmin()` and `K`, i.e. a fully working [mre]. Please [edit] your post to add those. That said, finding a minimum in a row is as easy as `[val, loc] = min(A;ii, :)`, where `val` will be the value of the minimum and `loc` its index on row `ii`. Calling `val = min(A, [], 2)`, yields the minimum on every row, but you cannot (easily) return the indices in the same call. See [the documentation on `min()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html).